# How to force turtles to move only in a half of the world?

Tags: netlogo

I created a world divided in two parts with the command `ask patches with [ pxcor < 0] [set pcolor blue] ask patches with [pxcor > 0] [set pcolor green]` .
In one of this there're 100 turtles, who 5 are infected and the same in the other part.
My problem is to force the turtles to move only in their part of the world. So I want that turtles with pcolor = blue move randomly in the second and third quadrant (pxcor <0) and turtles with pcolor = green in the first and fourth quadrant (pxcor> 0).  how do I do?

This is the code:

```
turtles-own

[
sick?
sick-time]


to setup

 ca
 ask patches with [ pxcor < 0 ] [set pcolor blue] ; we want divide the world in two parts: the blue one in the north of Italy
 ask patches with [pxcor > 0  ] [set pcolor green]; the white one is the south of Italy
 ask patches with [pxcor = 0 ] [set pcolor white ] ; represent the border
  
 create-turtles 200 ; we create a population made up for 200 people
 [ set size 1
  set shape "person"
  set sick-time 0
    get-healthy]
  
   ask n-of 100 turtles  ; 100 of this one live in north of Italy
 [setxy 12  random-ycor ]
  
   ask n-of 100 turtles ; another 100 in the south
 [setxy -12 random-ycor   
    ]
  
 
 ask n-of 5 turtles with [pcolor = blue] ; we want infect 5 people for each world
[get-sick ]
  
 ask n-of 5 turtles with [pcolor = green]
[get-sick ]


  reset-ticks

end



to get-healthy

  set sick? false
  set color white
end


to get-sick
set sick? true
set color yellow
set shape "circle"
set sick-time sick-time + 1

end



to go

  ask turtles
  [
    move ]
  tick

end



to move

rt random-float 360
fd 1

end
```

Comment: please give us more info. your programming language and an abstraction of your problem. also use ``` your code ``` for showing us your code.

Comment: I'll hope that now is more clear! thanks for your answer

Comment: You don't need to provide all the code, just the relevant bits. In this case, that is the procedures that split the world and that move the turtles.

Answer (score 1):

Your movement procedure looks like:

```
to move
  right random-float 360
  forward 1
end
```

If you want them to just stay where they are if moving would take them into the wrong half, then you can use `patch-ahead` to test the patch they'd be moving to. I think what you want is that they don't go to a different coloured patch. One way is:

```
to move
  right random-float 360
  if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = pcolor [forward 1]
end
```

`[pcolor] of patch-ahead 1` returns the colour of the patch that is one distance unit ahead, so where the turtle is trying to move to. `pcolor` is the colour of the patch that the turtle is currently standing on.